# Using results of a script in another one

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script to basically run one script (i.e script called `list`) that is already made, then take the results of the executed `list` script and add the listed items into another script that is made (let's call it `export`).

To break it down

```
list localhost
```

(this would then create a list)

```
0001 
0002
0003 
...
```

then I want to take the items listed (`0001`, `0002`, `0003`) and add them as parameters to another script (called `export`). This would then needed to be run as many times as there are items listed. So if there are 3 items in the list, `export` would run 3 times with the name of the items listed.

```
export 0001
export 0002
export 0003
```

Comment: Don't call your script `export`…

Comment: What if every time your first script finds a result (localhost) or for each local host, it calls your badly named `export` script (better call it `exportLocalHost`) that way you wont have to pipe the results of the first one to the other or create extra files...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input

Answer (score 3):

```
./list.sh localhost | while read -r item; do ./export.sh "$item"; done
```

Explanation:

- `./list.sh localhost` outputs the items
- `read -r item` reads one line of the output and save it to the variable `$item`. `-r` prevents `read` from expanding escape sequences in the input. Just in case.
- we do a `while` loop over all the lines (`while …; do …; done`) to call `export.sh` on all items

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the `read` command in a `while` loop you can use xargs:

```
./list localhost | xargs -L1 ./export.sh
```

`xargs -L1` calls `./export.sh` once for every line of output `./list localhost` produces. The line will be subject to word splitting. Meaning if `./list` outputs a line like `foo bar`, `xargs` will call `./export.sh` with two arguments: `foo` and `bar`. If you want to pass the whole line as a single argument instead like `./export.sh "foo bar" you can use the newline symbol as delimiter (with GNU xargs):

```
./list localhost | xargs -L1 -d '\n' ./export.sh
```

Another, portable, option (thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302758/using-results-of-a-script-in-another-one/41303779#comment69810107_41303779)) to control this behaviour is using the `-I` option to specify a placeholder for the argument and specify how it should be used in the command:

```
# Will call like ./export.sh "foo bar" (quoted as single argument)
./list localhost | xargs -I '{}' ./export.sh {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a 'piped' command to do what you want.

```
list localhost | myscript.sh
```

This will push output results from 'list localhost' into 'myscript.sh'.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `` in your command for getting the job done quickly:

```
for i in `./list localhost`; do ./export $i; done
```

Comment: `$()` is the preferred way, use that instead of backticks [here's why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)